# Agenda view for all tasks with a project tag and at a certain level

Tags: org-mode

Projects with multiple subprojects are tagged with `PROJ`, e.g.

```
** PROJ Master Project
*** PROJ Subproject 1
**** Task 1a
*** PROJ Subproject 2
**** Task 2a
```

Currently, I have a custom agenda view that will simply display all items with a `PROJ` tag:

```
("p" "all projects" todo "PROJ")
```

1. How do I modify it so that only master projects (which are all level 2 headings) are displayed?
2. How do I modify it so that only subprojects (level 3 or more) are displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `LEVEL` "property" to match a certain subtree level. The match syntax is described in `(info "(org) Matching tags and properties")`. `LEVEL=2` corresponds to subtrees with 2 stars etc. And to answer your questions:

```el
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("p" "master projects" tags-todo "LEVEL=2/PROJ")
        ("u" "subprojects" tags-todo "LEVEL>2/PROJ")))
```

Comment: Thanks! `tags-todo` is what I was missing. I had to change it to `LEVEL=2`, though, to match 2-star headings, so I guess the `LEVEL` property is 1-based instead of 0-based?

Comment: You're right, updated the answer.